# Connecting Hyperledger Sawtooth Validator to a Validator on a remote machine

Tags: docker, hyperledger-sawtooth

I'm trying to configure a sawtooth network with 5 Validators. One of them is on a remote machine. But this Validator can't connnect to the network. I'm using Docker on Linux.

I'm using the code of [this](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/master/app_developers_guide/docker_test_network.html) Sawtooth example.

First yaml. file of 4 validator:

```
version: '3.6'

volumes:
  pbft-shared:

services:

# -------------=== intkey tp ===-------------

  intkey-tp-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-intkey-tp-python:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-intkey-tp-python-default-0
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: intkey-tp-python -C tcp://validator-0:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  intkey-tp-1:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-intkey-tp-python:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-intkey-tp-python-default-1
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: intkey-tp-python -C tcp://validator-1:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  intkey-tp-2:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-intkey-tp-python:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-intkey-tp-python-default-2
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: intkey-tp-python -C tcp://validator-2:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  intkey-tp-3:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-intkey-tp-python:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-intkey-tp-python-default-3
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: intkey-tp-python -C tcp://validator-3:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

# -------------=== rest api ===-------------

  rest-api-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-default-0
    expose:
      - 8008
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth-rest-api \
          --connect tcp://validator-0:4004 \
          --bind rest-api-0:8008
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  rest-api-1:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-default-1
    expose:
      - 8008
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth-rest-api \
          --connect tcp://validator-1:4004 \
          --bind rest-api-1:8008
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  rest-api-2:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-default-2
    expose:
      - 8008
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth-rest-api \
          --connect tcp://validator-2:4004 \
          --bind rest-api-2:8008
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  rest-api-3:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-default-3
    expose:
      - 8008
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth-rest-api \
          --connect tcp://validator-3:4004 \
          --bind rest-api-3:8008
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

# -------------=== settings tp ===-------------

  settings-tp-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp-default-0
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: settings-tp -C tcp://validator-0:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  settings-tp-1:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp-default-1
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: settings-tp -C tcp://validator-1:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  settings-tp-2:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp-default-2
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: settings-tp -C tcp://validator-2:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  settings-tp-3:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp-default-3
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: settings-tp -C tcp://validator-3:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

# -------------=== shell ===-------------

  shell:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-shell:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-shell-default
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth keygen
        tail -f /dev/null
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

# -------------=== validators ===-------------

  validator-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-default-0
    expose:
      - 4004
      - 5050
      - 8800
    ports:
      - '8900:8800'
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    command: |
      bash -c "
        if [ -e /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.priv ]; then
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.priv /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv ]; then
          sawadm keygen
          mkdir -p /pbft-shared/validators || true
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.priv
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e config-genesis.batch ]; then
          sawset genesis -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv -o config-genesis.batch
        fi &&
        while [[ ! -f /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.pub || \
                 ! -f /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.pub || \
                 ! -f /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.pub || \
                 ! -f /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.pub ]];
        do sleep 1; done
        echo sawtooth.consensus.pbft.members=\\['\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.pub)'\"'\\] &&
        if [ ! -e config.batch ]; then
         sawset proposal create \
            -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv \
            sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.name=pbft \
            sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.version=1.0 \
            sawtooth.consensus.pbft.members=\\['\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.pub)'\"'\\] \
            sawtooth.publisher.max_batches_per_block=1200 \
            -o config.batch
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e /var/lib/sawtooth/genesis.batch ]; then
          sawadm genesis config-genesis.batch config.batch
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e /root/.sawtooth/keys/my_key.priv ]; then
          sawtooth keygen my_key
        fi &&
        sawtooth-validator -vv \
          --endpoint tcp://validator-0:8800 \
          --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
          --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
          --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
          --scheduler parallel \
          --peering static \
          --maximum-peer-connectivity 10000 \
          --network-auth trust
      "

  validator-1:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-default-1
    expose:
      - 4004
      - 5050
      - 8800
    ports:
      - '8901:8800'
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    command: |
      bash -c "
        if [ -e /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.priv ]; then
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.pub /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.priv /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv ]; then
          sawadm keygen
          mkdir -p /pbft-shared/validators || true
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.pub
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.priv
        fi &&
        sawtooth keygen my_key &&
        sawtooth-validator -vv \
          --endpoint tcp://validator-1:8800 \
          --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
          --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
          --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
          --scheduler parallel \
          --peering static \
          --maximum-peer-connectivity 10000 \
          --network-auth trust \
          --peers tcp://validator-0:8800
      "

  validator-2:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-default-2
    expose:
      - 4004
      - 5050
      - 8800
    ports:
      - '8902:8800'
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    command: |
      bash -c "
        if [ -e /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.priv ]; then
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.pub /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.priv /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv ]; then
          sawadm keygen
          mkdir -p /pbft-shared/validators || true
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.pub
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.priv
        fi &&
        sawtooth keygen my_key &&
        sawtooth-validator -vv \
          --endpoint tcp://validator-2:8800 \
          --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
          --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
          --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
          --scheduler parallel \
          --peering static \
          --maximum-peer-connectivity 10000 \
          --network-auth trust \
          --peers tcp://validator-0:8800 \
          --peers tcp://validator-1:8800
      "

  validator-3:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-default-3
    expose:
      - 4004
      - 5050
      - 8800
    ports:
      - '8903:8800'
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    command: |
      bash -c "
        if [ -e /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.priv ]; then
         cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.pub /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub
         cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.priv /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv ]; then
         sawadm keygen
         mkdir -p /pbft-shared/validators || true
         cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.pub
         cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.priv
        fi &&
        sawtooth keygen my_key &&
        sawtooth-validator -vv \
          --endpoint tcp://validator-3:8800 \
          --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
          --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
          --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
          --scheduler parallel \
          --peering static \
          --maximum-peer-connectivity 10000 \
          --network-auth trust \
          --peers tcp://validator-0:8800 \
          --peers tcp://validator-1:8800 \
          --peers tcp://validator-2:8800
      "

# -------------=== pbft engines ===-------------

  pbft-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-pbft-engine:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-pbft-engine-default-0
    command: pbft-engine -vv --connect tcp://validator-0:5050
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  pbft-1:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-pbft-engine:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-pbft-engine-default-1
    command: pbft-engine -vv --connect tcp://validator-1:5050
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  pbft-2:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-pbft-engine:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-pbft-engine-default-2
    command: pbft-engine -vv --connect tcp://validator-2:5050
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  pbft-3:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-pbft-engine:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-pbft-engine-default-3
    command: pbft-engine -vv --connect tcp://validator-3:5050
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

# -------------=== xo tps ===-------------

  xo-tp-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-xo-tp-python:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-xo-tp-python-default-0
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: xo-tp-python -vv -C tcp://validator-0:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  xo-tp-1:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-xo-tp-python:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-xo-tp-python-default-1
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: xo-tp-python -vv -C tcp://validator-1:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  xo-tp-2:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-xo-tp-python:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-xo-tp-python-default-2
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: xo-tp-python -vv -C tcp://validator-2:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  xo-tp-3:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-xo-tp-python:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-xo-tp-python-default-3
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: xo-tp-python -vv -C tcp://validator-3:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL
```

The second yaml. file of the last validator:

```
version: '3.6'

volumes:
  pbft-shared:

services:

# -------------=== intkey tp ===-------------

  intkey-tp-4:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-intkey-tp-python:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-intkey-tp-python-default-4
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: intkey-tp-python -C tcp://validator-4:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

# -------------=== rest api ===-------------

  rest-api-4:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-default-4
    expose:
      - 8008
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth-rest-api \
          --connect tcp://validator-4:4004 \
          --bind rest-api-4:8008
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

# -------------=== settings tp ===-------------

  settings-tp-4:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp-default-4
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: settings-tp -C tcp://validator-4:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

# -------------=== shell ===-------------

  shell:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-shell:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-shell-default
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth keygen
        tail -f /dev/null
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

# -------------=== validators ===-------------

  validator-4:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-default-4    
    expose:
      - 4004
      - 5050
      - 8800
    ports:
      - '8904:8800'
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    command: |
      bash -c "
        if [ -e /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.priv ]; then
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.pub /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.priv /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv ]; then
          sawadm keygen
          mkdir -p /pbft-shared/validators || true
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.pub
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.priv
        fi &&
        sawtooth keygen my_key &&
        sawtooth-validator -vv \
          --endpoint tcp://validator-4:8800 \
          --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
          --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
          --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
          --scheduler parallel \
          --peering static \
          --maximum-peer-connectivity 10000 \
          --network-auth trust \
          --peers tcp://192.168.69.175:8900 \
          --peers tcp://192.168.69.175:8901 \
          --peers tcp://192.168.69.175:8902 \
          --peers tcp://192.168.69.175:8903
      "

# -------------=== pbft engines ===-------------

  pbft-4:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-pbft-engine:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-pbft-engine-default-4
    command: pbft-engine -vv --connect tcp://validator-4:5050
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

# -------------=== xo tps ===-------------

  xo-tp-4:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-xo-tp-python:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-xo-tp-python-default-4
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: xo-tp-python -vv -C tcp://validator-4:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL
```

The last validator got this message: "No response from OutboundConnectionThread.... seconds - removing connection."

Comment: I assume your host network setup has multiple network interfaces enabled. Please check the logs in the first host (one of the validator nodes numbered from 0 through 3), see if the peering request is being sent from the IP in the subnet you're expecting. Example in your case it should be 192.168.X.X.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have TCP port 8080 open on both sides, besides having networking functional (try `ping`).

If you have multiple Docker containers, see the Docker network documentation on how to setup networking.